# Dell Vostro 3350 switchable graphics force to use only one graphic card

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, graphics-card, dell-vostro

I have a *Dell Vostro 3350* Laptop with switchable graphics capability. It has two graphic cards:

1. Intel HD Graphics 3000
2. AMD Radeon HD 7470M

I downloaded the driver of two cards from Dell's official download center and installed successfully. Now when I connect the adapter cable, my laptop use AMD card automatically and then I disconnect it, my laptop use Intel card. I wan't to use Intel card in any situation. There isn't any option in *Catalyst Control Center* to force to use only one card. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works on every dell laptop with switchable graphic cards.

1. Go to `Catalyst Control Center` and use second method (Choosing graphic card base on power source).
2. Go to `Power Option` of Windows and choose your `Power Plan` (e.g Balanced) and go to its advanced settings
3. Find `Switchable Graphics Settings` and select `Power-saving Graphics` all options under it. Click OK to save changes. (See below)

[image]

[Refrence](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3519/t/19499399)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the same as HP's with similar configurations, and if the proper drivers are loaded, you should have three Switchable Graphics property options in CCC.

Navigate to Power - Switchable Graphics Global Settings... Remember that these settings are over-ridden by application specific settings, except in the case of "Force Power Saving Graphics" is set. Here you can set the graphics options to use based on battery or A/C power connection.